# type mismatch in vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, vlookup

I am attempting to do the following:

1. Look at the first row's column B (Event) from entiresalespipeline
2. Match Column B to a table (Events_and_Activities) that links a date to each event
3. If that date is in the future, copy the entire row into the next empty row in a third worksheet (CurrentSalesPipeline)
4. Repeat this process until there are no more filled rows in the first spreadsheet.

I have created the following code, which when I mouse-over the text appears to give correct data, but which gives me the following error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

```
Sub ShowUpcoming_Click()

Dim rCell As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim DateConf As Long

For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("B3:B5000")

Set ws = Worksheets("CurrentSalesPipeline") 

DateConf = Application.VLookup(rCell, Worksheets("Events_and_Activities").Range("A2:B12"), 2, False)
Range("A1").Value = DateConf

If CDate(DateConf) >= CDate((Date)) Then
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
        With ws
            .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("A3:A3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("B3:B3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("C3:C3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("D3:D3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("E3:E3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("F3:F3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("G3:G3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("H3:H3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("I3:I3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("J3:J3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("K3:K3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("L3:L3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("M3:M3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("N3:N3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("O3:O3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("P3:P3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("Q3:Q3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("R3:R3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("S3:S3").Value
            .Cells(iRow, 20).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("T3:T3").Value
            End With
            End If
Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but which gives me the following error"? Where exactly do you see the error? Is there a specific line of code giving you the error or are you seeing it somewhere else?

Comment: 1. You don't confirm that VLookup returned a date. 2) You try to turn that unknown return value to a date using CDate(DateConf). The error shows you exactly what line caused it, and a breakpoint on that line would show you the error.

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but that large block of value copying can be replaced with one line: `ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, 20).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Range("A1").Resize(1, 20).Value`

Comment: If you got that code to work, I would suggest you bring it to [codereview.se], as there are a number of ways to significantly improve scalability, readability and perhaps even performance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `DateConf` as a `Long`:

```
Dim DateConf As Long
```

And then assigning it the result of the `VLookup` call:

```
DateConf = Application.VLookup(rCell, Worksheets("Events_and_Activities").Range("A2:B12"), 2, False)
```

That's a lot of assumptions to make: you're relying on VBA to perform an implicit conversion of the returned value to a `Long`, without knowing if the returned value will be a valid numeric.

What if the `VLookup` returns an empty string? What if it returned an `#N/A` error value?

```
Dim lookupResult As Variant
lookupResult = Application.VLookup(rCell, Worksheets("Events_and_Activities").Range("A2:B12"), 2, False)

If IsNumeric(lookupResult) Then
    DateConf = CLng(lookupResult)
    ...
End If
```

Reduce the number of assumptions you're making, you'll reduce the number of potential issues by as much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your very thoughtful and extremely helpful input!
After some tinkering, I managed to come up with the following, which does everything I need it to do.

Mat's Mug - your suggestion was perfect!
Tim Williams - I tried your single line solution to the copy/pasting, but it only copied the first line (headings) over every line in the range, so I stuck with what I had.

```
Sub ShowUpcoming_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateConf As Long
Dim r As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("CurrentSalesPipeline")
Dim lookupresult  As Variant
'find last completed row of entire spreadsheet
lastrow = Worksheets("EntireSalesPipeline").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'From the first completed line (row 3) to last completed row
    For r = 3 To lastrow
        'lookup conference date from events/activities spreadsheet
    lookupresult = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("EntireSalesPipeline").Cells(r, 2).Value, Worksheets("Events_and_activities").Range("A2:B13"), 2, False)
        If IsNumeric(lookupresult) Then
        DateConf = CLng(lookupresult)
        End If
    'If vlookup finds a date, then check to make sure it is in the future from when the button was hit.
    If CDate(DateConf) >= CDate((Date)) Then
    'If it is a future event, then copy that data into the current spreadsheet
            iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
            With ws
                .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 1).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 2).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 3).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 4).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 5).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 6).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 7).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 8).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 9).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 10).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 11).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 12).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 13).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 14).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 15).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 16).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 16).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 17).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 17).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 18).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 18).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 19).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 19).Value
                .Cells(iRow, 20).Value = Worksheets("entiresalespipeline").Cells(r, 20).Value
            End With
    End If
'Repeat for next line in existing
Next r
End Sub
```

This is a great community. Thank you again!
Sarah